# Wordpress single post file not found

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm working on a plugin which shows a portfolio.
I've added a custom post type function, but when I go to the single page it won't recognize the single-portfolio.php.

What I've tried is:

```
    if(post_type == 'portfolio')
    {
        if(is_single())
        {
            include('single-portfolio.php');
        }
    }
```

My single-portfolio.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
 if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
        the_title();
        if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        endif;
?>
        <?php $site= get_post_custom_values('projLink'); 
            if($site[0] != ""){
        ?>
            <p><a href="<?=$site[0]?>">Live Preview</a></p>

        <?php }else{ ?>
            <p><em>Live link not available</em></p>
        <?php }
    endwhile;
endif;
?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My plugin structure:

```
devplugin\devplugin.php
devplugin\posttype.php
devplugin\template.php
devplugin\addtemplate.php
devplugin\single-portfolio.php
devplugin\devplugin.css
devplugin\css\bootstrap.min.css
```

Thanks,
Rens Manders

Comment: What error is showing up either a blank page or 404 page..

Comment: it's using the single.php file from the theme itself, it looks like he cant see the single-portfolio.php file

Comment: Have a try like this Hide the `single-portfolio.php` over there and create your custom file and check whether the page opens up or not. and let me know

Comment: when i hide the single.php file from the theme, it has no style, and it still wont recognize the plugin's single-portfolio.php file.

Comment: If you are working under the plugin you need to have full control over the plugin alone. Don't disturb the functionality that they have written in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your `single-portfolio.php` file is in your plugin's directory. WordPress won't be looking there for a template file.

You need to either put it in the theme folder or use a filter to add your plugin as one of the directories templates can be loaded from.

If this is going to be a plugin you plan to release I'd be looking at loading from the plugin directory while still giving users the option to override from their theme.